# an object is required for the non-static field

Tags: c#, enums, compiler-errors, arguments

There really isn't much going on here. I've simplified the code down to this small segment that wont compile. Again the error is "an object is required for the non-static field, method, or property."

```
public class Scorer
{   
    public enum ScoringCategory {FullHouse}

    public int getScore(ScoringCategory category)
    {
        return 1; 
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ScoringTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFullHouse()
    {                                    
        // Here is where I get the error
        int myScore = Scorer.getScore(Scorer.ScoringCategory.FullHouse);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scorer scorer = new Scorer();  
int myScore = scorer .getScore(Scorer.ScoringCategory.FullHouse);`

Comment: or add static: public static int getScore(ScoringCategory category)

Comment: your class  "Scorer" is not static.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create an instance of `Scorer`, as it is an *instance method*, which is declared on an instance of a type, not the type itself (like a `static` method):

```
var scorer = new Scorer();
int myScore = scorer.getScore(Scorer.ScoringCategory.FullHouse);
```

Comment: Thank you! I am making the transition from C++.

Answer (score 0):

your method getScore is an instance method of class `Scorer`. You need to create an object of type `Scorer` before you can use that method.

This would work:

```
public class Scorer
{   
    public enum ScoringCategory {FullHouse}

    public int getScore(ScoringCategory category)
    {
        return 1; 
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ScoringTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFullHouse()
    {                 
        // create an instance                   
        var scorerInstance = new Scorer();
        // call instance method getScore
        int myScore = scorerInstance.getScore(Scorer.ScoringCategory.FullHouse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the enum from the encapsulating class and making it static so you can use it as you're trying to:

```
public static enum ScoringCategory {FullHouse}    
public class Scorer
{
    public int getScore(ScoringCategory category)
    {
        return 1; 
    }
}
```